# Delete sub string between two characters of Pandas Data frame with python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

I want to delete the character between "()" and "[]" of the column named 'RegionName'. The image of the DataFrame is given below.[Screenshort of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdUvN.png) 
Please, tell me how can I do that!

Comment: df['RegionName'].str.replace(...)

Comment: You want the keep the brackets and the square brackets or remove them as well?

Comment: @Zubair Hossian Do you want to keep () and [] after deleting the characters between them

Comment: @Erfan I need exactly what you have done.Thank you.

Comment: @min2bro No, I don't want to keep () or [].

Comment: @ZubairHossian Already added my answer yesterday, Will appreciate if you can upvote

Comment: @min2bro I have upvoted, but my reputation is less than 15 so that it is not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str.replace` with regex operator which deletes everything after the first `(` character:

**Input data**

```
                                RegionName
0            Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
1  Florence (University of Nother Alabama)
```

**Output**

```
df['RegionName'].str.replace('\(.*$', '')

0      Auburn 
1    Florence 
Name: RegionName, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove () and [] after deleting the characters then you can do it with replace and regex

```
df.replace("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "",regex=True)
```

**Input:**

```
Auburn(Auburn University)[1]
```

**Output:**

```
Auburn
```